# Why android try to load class when not use it?

Tags: android, classloader

I have an android studio project, it use jar A , the jar A will use jar B. jar B did not exist in compile time. the compiler works fine and output apk. (I also write source code for jar A and jar B).

When I run the apk, I get below information from logcat:

```
07-19 15:20:30.537 14788 14788 I art     : Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.cloudtech.ads.core.f>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/cloudtech/image/Callback;

07-19 15:20:30.537 14788 14788 I art     : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.cloudtech.image.Callback" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.phone.sample-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.phone.sample-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.phone.sample-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
```

for my understanding, classloader will load class before it use such class.

From logcat, It show classloader try to load class in jar B. but I am sure my code did not use class from jar B at that moment.